# Convert\Cast a generic list to a generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics

I have a simple Azure search service that I'm trying to make generic but I'm struggling with the `return` part.

```
public class AzureSearchService<T> : IAzureSearchProvider<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<TResult> Search<TResult>(string searchText, string filter, 
        Func<T, TResult> mapping)
    {
        DocumentSearchResult<T> response = indexClient.Documents
            .Search<T>(searchText, searchParameters);

        return response.Results.Select(r => r.Document).ToList();
    }
}
```

I suspect this will be something simple, but I'm getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type to `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<TResult>`. An explicit conversion exists (Are you missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't using the `mapping` parameter anywhere but that's the only way to convert a `T` to a `TResult`. Maybe you need `response.Results.Select(mapping).ToList();`? What's the type of `response.Results`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to use your `mapping` parameter? You should use it!

```
return response.Results
            .Select(r => r.Document)
            .Select(mapping)
            .ToList(); // you don't need ToList here, unless you don't want the results to be lazy
```

`mapping` is the function that converts each `T` in your list to `TResult`.

Comment: The first `Select` doesn't make sense unless `T` did have a constraint that has a `Document` property (which it doesn't in the shown code, it only has a `class` constraint). More likely just the `Select(mapping)`, but more details would be needed on the question itself

Comment: @Jcl `Document` is of type `T`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchresultbase-1.document?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchResultBase_1_Document)

Comment: ah, hadn't even seen the API, I suspected the `Search<T>` would return an `IEnumerable<T>` and not an `IEnumerable<Object that has T as document>`. You are right. Upvoting here

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a List of `Document` objects but signing the method with a return type of `IEnumerable<TResult>`... so unless `TResult` is a type of whatever `Document` is (which would need a constraint, on both `T` and `TResult`), those are not directly convertible.

There's a `mapping` parameter which seems to be a converter/projection function, so you may want to use:

```
return response.Results.Select(mapping);
```

PS: as found by @Sweeper by looking at the API, that'd be:

```
return response.Results.Select(x => Document).Select(mapping);
```

Answer (score -2):

Whats the relation between the type `TResult` and the type of `r.Document`. Are you missing a constraint on `TResult` maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you intended this to be an answer?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, the problem is that there is no cast between `TResult` and whatever `r.Document` is. Why is it you belief this isn't a valid answer?

Comment: This only asks 2 questions while giving a doubted suggestion, it certainly doesn't sound like an answer